# WordPress Access Denied Issue

Tags: wordpress

I have two pages created on WordPress. the first page consists of a button that is part of a form that will do a POST request to another page on the site. The 2 pages require the user to log in first before they can access it. I used Auth0 plugin for WordPress to handle logging in onto the CMS.

First Page:

```
<form class="toFormButton" method="POST" action="<site_url>/formpage">
   <input type="hidden" name="redirectFrom" value="redirect">
   <input id="nextButton" type="submit" value="NEXT">
</form>
```

When clicking the next button, this error shows up with code 500:
[image]

The weird thing is that, when I refresh the browser, the second page is able to load without any errors. I have thought and researched much on why or how this weird phenomenon can happen but have not found a solution to fix it. I checked the request headers and form data of both the failed POST request and the successful POST request and they are similar. Has anyone experienced this before or knows how to fix it.

Comment: This issue only happens during a POST request only

Comment: good day dear @guidance_seeker  - have lots of thank for your idea sharing here.  This is a important thread. Many thanks for all!